# Vbscript execute a function rarely, with chances using random

Tags: loops, random, vbscript, call

New to Vbscript.
I made a random function with two parameters.And called it
It resulted in a infinite loop opening infinite program.

```
Function random(v1,v2)
 Randomize
 rdm =(Int((v2 - v1 + 1)* Rnd + v1))
End Function 

Function download()
 Set shell = createobject("wscript.shell"):shell.run "mspaint.exe"   
End function

'I want this download function to run rarely
Do
  Call random(100,1000)
  If  rdm>700 And rdm <760 Then 
  Call download()
  End If
loop
```

Comment: You have a Do...Loop there; where is the terminating condition for the loop? You're calling the function to generate the random number but not storing it anywhere. Did you mean to assign the return value to ram?

Comment: I want to know if i can multi task using vbscript . Run a loop - for a specific function as well as sleep for some other function at the same time . c++ and others are capable . Does vbscript allow me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added code to `return` value and Added `Exit Do` statement to break the loop.

Hope this will help you..

```
Function random(v1,v2)
 Randomize
 random=(Int((v2 - v1 + 1)* Rnd + v1))
End Function 

Function download()
 Set shell = createobject("wscript.shell"):shell.run "mspaint.exe"   
 download=true
End function

'I want this download function to run rarely
Do
  rdm= random(100,1000)
  If  rdm>700 And rdm <760 Then 
  Call download()
  Exit Do  ' this will break the loop if condition is met 
  End If
loop
```

Comment: That fixes OP's infinite loop bug, but note that the way you have it now, `download()` is virtually certain to run within milliseconds since the loop will run until the triggering condition is true. On the other hand, it really isn't clear what OP was trying to do with a loop anyway.

Comment: I am new to vbscript . Is there any formula using which i can call a function rarely. Like 3 times a day ? With a `do-loop` structure , Wonder how much chances will i have to increase , confused.

Comment: Many ways we can do this(calling functions 3 times a day). Confirm me what is you exact requirement like: (1). At random times, (2) at 3 Partcular times (3) if any event trigger occurs. etc.,

Comment: @KiranMaroju at random times 3 times a day

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to write a script which, when called, invokes a function with probability 60/900 = 1/15, you are making things too complicated. There is no reason to generate a random integer in the range 100 to 1000 just to check if it lies in a certain range. If you want to trigger an action with probability `p`, have a line which looks like:

```
If rnd() < p Then 'action
```

If I understand your intentions, your entire script could be written as:

```
Randomize

Set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")   

If rnd() < 1/15 Then shell.Run "mspaint.exe"
```

Most of the time you run the above script nothing happens, but an average of 1/15 times it will open paint.

Comment: Above code seems to provide me with mspaint.exe a lot quicker than the number chances i used .

Comment: `rnd()` simulates a uniformly distributed random variable in [0,1]. Thus `rnd() < p` should be true with probability `p`. Statistical tests can be used to confirm this or disconfirm this. I would be surprised if causal use could detect any departure from a uniform distribution. `rnd()` is only pseudorandom so it isn't perfect, but it should be close enough for any casual purpose.